# Booting a GPT USB key on older BIOS laptop

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, gpt

I have an old HP EliteBook 8530p, which does not support booting from GPT USB (GPT HDDs are fine though). Lately I had the wish to have a fast-to-start OS for browsing, smaller web tasks, etc., so I grabbed a ChromeOS build (latest one by [ArnoldTheBat](http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/)), flashed it on an 8GB flash drive, and popped it in. It did not boot, so I dug deeper and discovered that it actually is GPT, and cannot be converted to MBR.

As my laptop does not support UEFI booting from USB (there's a really-really beta UEFI support in the BIOS, but as I said, it only supports GPT hard drives, not USB devices), I'm stuck. Is there any way of booting it, say, another flash drive with a specific boot loader/manager (e.g. Plop)?

Comment: Just because it’s GPT doesn’t mean it doesn’t contain BIOS boot code. I’ll try it later.

Comment: I've tested this theory multiple times - as soon as a drive is in GPT format, the BIOS actively refuses to use it, it won't even start to read the drive to search for boot code. It can be a Windows installer, Ubuntu live disk, anything, as long as it's GPT, it won't boot.

Comment: Well, it crashes but both the VirtualBox image and the raw image contain BIOS boot code. Maybe you’ll be able to disable UEFI somehow (“Legacy Only” or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite a while after and you might have found a solution but for the record, I'll post an answer.

ALthough you cannot boot a GPT in BIOS bios, you can change the USB to a MBR partition table, currently it is GPT.

*NOTE - I believe promoting software is against rules, but there is no other way for me to post a solution, these software are freeware.*

**You can do this in several OS's:**

**Windows** : [AOMEI Partition](http://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html) which allows partition table changes. There are also a few small USB utilites that allow low level formats and partition tables, a quick Google search should list them.

**Linux** : You may use [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) which is also the goto disk management application for Linux

There are also a few live-cd options, but then again, who would use that to change a flash?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another way that I have successfully used on HP EliteBook 2560p is to use the "**Boot from EFI file**" option.

While this particular model doesn't support UEFI boot from anything else but the internal HDD or network, the "Boot from EFI file" will actually recognize all attached drives including USB thumb drives. A simple file explorer will appear allowing you to navigate to the EFI file on the attached drives, including GPT partitioned USB stick.

As an example, to boot a Ubuntu 16 USB stick, you would navigate to: `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI`